# Sort indexPathsForSelectedRows in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, tableview

When you invoke tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows(), it returns an array of AnyObject type with the indexPaths of the rows selected in the order that user has selected them.

What I want is to sort the indexPaths in order to get ascending order. Before Swift, it could be achieved with this:

```
NSArray *sortedIndexPaths = [[tableView indexPathsforSelectedRows]
sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

But I have tried to implement it with Swift and it does not work :S

Anyone knows how to deal with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

it's simple code to sort array of NSIndexPath objects stored in **paths** variable .
The trick is in casting to **[NSIndexPath]**. Now you can have your array sorted.

```
let paths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() as [NSIndexPath]
let sortedArray = paths.sorted {$0.row < $1.row}
```

OR
if you wish to have separate function for that like:

```
func compare (obj0: NSIndexPath, obj1: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
 return obj0.row < obj1.row
}
```

then

```
let sortedArray = paths.sorted { compare($0, $1) }
```

Comment: You don't need casting. IndexPath implements Comparable protocol, so you can just simply: `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows.sorted()`.

Comment: yes, note: answer was posted 6 years ago for the Swift 1.0

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Windows 7 at the moment so I cannot test but this is what I would expect to work. It may need a type annotation.

```
let paths = tableView.indexPathsforSelectedRows()
let sorted = paths.sortedArrayUsingSelector("compare:")
```

Comment: No, it does not work. I had tried this with no successful before.. Error: [AnyObject]? does not have a member named 'sortedArrayUsingSelector'

Comment: That's because paths is an Optional, see Allen Zeng's answer RE: using a guard statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can overload the `<` and `>` operators and then just call sort on it.

Define this globally

```
func <(left: NSIndexPath, right: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return left.section < right.section || left.row < right.row
}
```

Then you can just do this for ascending

```
let sortedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.sort(<)
```

Obviously because of it returns an optional you would guard against it somehow, for example

```
guard let sortedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.sort(<) else {
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Sort indexPathsForSelectedRows swift 4 code.

```
    if var selection = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
    {
       selection = selection.sorted{ $1.compare($0) == .orderedAscending }

    }
```

If you have any issue ping me.